# My Android TextView is not showing ó properly?

Tags: android, android-fonts

I'm trying to reproduce an error where users have seen corrupted `TextViews`.

It's a standard `TextView` using the default font and it's not correctly displaying the `ó` latin character.

Instead it looks like this:

[image: example of incorrectly displayed ó]

what could be causing this? It's an older app, with `minSdkVersion` 14.

I've read that `SDK` 15 added some latin font improvements.

I created a new app with `minSdkVersion` 14 and it displays just fine.

Is there a tool like "Layout Inspector" I can use that can identify exactly what font is being used in a `TextView`?

Comment: Please share your code which is problematic. Cz, I found no issue using your `ó` font yet.
As you asked for `layout inspector` here is the link : https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector

Comment: Textview is using its default font defined in android studio maybe ROBOTO but if you want to show this type of textview you have to use unicodes or typefaces. because in android these text words are not defined

Comment: Tray to use AppCompatTextView instead

Comment: Use custom latin font ttf to show these font.